# gvim: Traces of previously opened files seen when reading a file

Tags: vim

I am seeing this strange issue where if I open a file in gvim on linux.

For e.g, if I am reading file2 in gvim, some of the lines in file2 have traces of file1 I had opened earlier.  Here are the snapshots of the original contents of file1, file2 and also a snapshot showing file1 overlapping file2.

[image]
>

As seen in the snapshots, traces of file1 is present while reading file2 (highlighted).

How to fix this?

Comment: Try `:redraw` command to see if the content of `file2` is restored.

Comment: @jdhao, no, that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You need to provide your system version, gvim version, minimal settings and steps to reproduce your problem. Currently, it is not clear the cause of your problem.

Comment: This is bozarre... There's most probably something wrong with your GVim or with your Linux setup... Does it change anything if you set a background color for your syntax highlighting though? `:hi Normal guibg=white` or similar?

Comment: filbranden, that seems to work.  Thanks!